Why does python allow there to be no __new__ method?
Why does python allow there to be no __new__ method in a class, whereas __init__ is mandatory?
For example, if you want to create an instance of 'Class A', you simple call A() and an object is created. What is the point of the __new__ class if creating an instance does the job already?
Edit:
example:
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello world")

A()

entering this into python will print "hello world", as an instance of class A, yet there is no __new__ method in the class.

That is a strong assertion. Can you provide any evidence?

https://builtin.com/data-science/new-python

@Phantom that's not evidence, hell even using __init__ isn't mandatory you can test this with class A: pass; print(A()) (yes it's a oneliner bc formatting in comments sucks) also, this question may be relevant

The __init__() method is not mandatory. Do the answers to this question help at all?

There's a duality involved. You rarely need to override __new__, because object.__new__ does all the hard work. You frequently need to override __init__, because object.__init__, if it does anything, doesn't do anything your script has to worry about.


__new__ is always called when created an object of a class A, when not defined the Object.__new__ is used.

Both __init__ and __new__ handle different concerns, __init__ is concerned about the object initial state while __new__ is concerned about how the object is created.


So both __init___ and __new__ are important and they both serve different purposes.
